# Не получается сделать привязку таблиц бд между собой

Tags: база-данных, visual-studio, sql-server

Уже в нескольких уроках видел что клацают ПКМ и создают привязку таблиц.
Но у меня по ПКМ совсем другое меню появляется на том же месте.

Мой софт: 
Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 + SQL Server Express 2012

Скриншот с видеоуроков:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скриншот с моего стола:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы не могли бы дать ссылку на урок, который смотрите? По скриншотам больше похоже на то, что в уроке используют Sql Server Management Studio, а Вы - Visual Studio.

Comment: https://www.techdays.ru/videos/3309.html
єто вижуалка: http://prntscr.com/80nrax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `Visual Studio 2013` так теперь, по всей видимости, уже не получится делать.

Теперь, чтобы добавить связь между таблицами нужно:

1. Кликнуть по надписи `Foreign Keys` справа от определения колонок таблицы и выбрать `Add New Foreign Key`
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Присвоить `foreign key` иия и нажать <kbd>Enter</kbd>. После этого, в скрипте создания таблицы, появится новая строка с объявлением`foreign key`
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. Поправить строку с объявлением `foreign key` указав нужные колонки и таблицу на которую нужно ссылаться
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Или** можно использовать вместо `Visual Studio` - `Sql Server Management Studio`, которую можно [скачать](http://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/download/details.aspx?id=8961) для `Sql Server Express`.
Там будет интерфейс, похожий на скриншот из видеоуроков:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]